# How to install a washing machine outlet box on the inside wall

Tags: walls

I have a metal building and my walls are thin. However it is installed and sheet rocked. This is what we call are game room and all my plumbing is on the inside walls covered with foam tubing
   I have been told sence my water lines or on the inside I can not put a 90 degree angle into the wall and a 90 into the box? Is this true will it slow down my presure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with multiple 90 degree elbows. Yes there will be some friction loss due to the elbows, slightly affecting your flow rate; no it will not make any difference, your washing machine may take a few extra seconds to fill up is all. Describing the situation exactly will help you get the best answer.

Comment: Thats good to know on the multi  angles, like i was saying i would like to mount the washing machine box on the inside wall not in it, reason being it could freeze in the winter this being a metal building is my concern. Is this a bad ideal and what could  I do to make the box look not so tacky.

Comment: Build a wood box frame (no back or front, just sides) sized so the box screws to it. Paint it nice, run the pipes through it into the valve box. Or build it big, with a plywood front cut out for the box, so the pipes don't show at all. If you take your time it will look fine.

Comment: Too many bends too fast in the **drain plumbing** can get interesting when the washer pumps out. The fill plumbing cares not. The drain will spit out the hose if it's too restricted...

Comment: Agreed, less than brand new machines discharge a lot of water fast and bends will perhaps cause overflow. Use or build a standpipe of appropriate height and diameter to accommodate your drain requirements. http://www.naturalhandyman.com/iip/infapplianceinstallation/i/washing_machine/2Typical_standpipe_drain.png